# Find Closest next hour

Tags: c#, datetime

Hi can anyone say how to find the closest hour with c#

```
string target='13:10';
List<string> hours = ['4:30', '12:10', '15:3', '22:00'];
```

The result must be 15:3

Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: Posting here looking for a cut-and-paste solution, it would appear.

Comment: Write real C# code to get started.  And lose the strings, use DateTime.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense, the closest hour would be 12:10, not 15:30.

Comment: `15:3` isn't anything, but if you meant `15:30` then it isn't the closest hour (or time), `12:10` is.  More rules needed.  Also, this code won't compile.  Strings are `"` double quote delimited in C#, Chars are single quotes `'`.

Comment: @Prisoner - The title mentioned closest **next** hour.

Comment: var result = hours.OrderByDesc().FirstOrDefault(x=> target <= x);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your list is sorted, you can simply select the first element that is greater than or equal to the target:

```
string result = hours.First(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x) >= TimeSpan.Parse(target));
```

Comment: Good answer, but really you should use `FirstOrDefault` otherwise changing target to `23:10` blows up.

Comment: But in mycase we always have values and for that reason it perfectly fits my need. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a LINQ query, I suppose.

Assuming you actually have an array of `DateTime` rather than `string`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var target = new DateTime(2011, 10, 17, 13, 10, 0);
        IEnumerable<DateTime> choices = GetChoices();
        var closest = choices.OrderBy(c => Math.Abs(target.Subtract(c).TotalMinutes)).First();
        Console.WriteLine(closest);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetChoices()
    {
        return new[]
                   {
                       new DateTime(2011, 10, 17, 4, 30, 0), 
                       new DateTime(2011, 10, 17, 12, 10, 0), 
                       new DateTime(2011, 10, 17, 15, 30, 0), 
                       new DateTime(2011, 10, 17, 22, 00, 0), 
                   };
    }
}
```

I've tried this out and actually I get `12:10` as the result, but you get the idea.